# bootstrap datetimepicker Unable to parse french months with accent

Tags: javascript, momentjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

unable to parse french months with accent like [février, décembre, août] , the others parsed without problems.

```
 <input data-datetimepicker="true" data-options="{'useCurrent':false,'format':'D MMMM YYYY'}" value="23 février 2018" >
```

Comment: Did you try using language:fr in your data options?

Comment: Yes without success, only months with accent not works...  I think it's an issue with accented characters and not specific for french

Comment: @fmh can you provide a snippet or a fiddle showing the issue?